# Polynomial over finite field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

I'm currently reading [these notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/PSLnsimple.pdf) on the simplicity of $PSL_n(F)$. At page 5 it is used that there exists an element x in fields with 4 or more elements such that both:

- $x\neq 0$
- $x^2-1\neq 0$

I have learned, though, that arguments like `a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ zero points' doesn't work in finite fields. So, why is the above statement true?

Comment: The statement about zeroes of polynomials works fine in finite fields. Anyway, the statement is just that there is a non-zero element that does not square to $1$, which is clear since inverses are unique.

Comment: That statement about polynomials of degree $n$ holds for all over integral domains. The usual proof via polynomial factoring works. The generalization fails after that. For example commutativity of the ring is absolutely essential. Anyway, good for you to question the validity of familiar arguments in an unfamiliar setting. Even better to remember the ingredients of the said argument so that you can later check their validity in a more general setting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\forall x\in F:$ $x=0$ or $(x+1)(x-1)=0$, then $x=0$ or $x=1$ or $x=-1$ are the only possible values of $x$ (maybe $1=-1$). But the field has at least four elements...

Comment: Thanks, I somehow forgot that $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$...